# Bibliography: how to move 'MISC' category to end of bibliography, and make 'BOOK' category first

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, sorting, books

I have many books in bibliography and also need to have 2 websites. I have added it as 'misc', but it appeared at the beginning of bibliography. Could someone help me and tell how to make the 'books' first on the list of bibliography ?

**[EDITED DETAILS]
Thank you, sir. So let's do a test:**

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,french,spanish,russian,polish]{babel}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wprowadzenie}
\section{Cel pracy}
\label{cha:teza}
TEXT TEXT TEXT \cite{BAHaero}, \cite{matlab1}.

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{moje}
\end{document}
```

**moje.bib**

```
@misc{matlab1,
  title = {MathWorks Documentation},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.mathworks.com/}},
  note = {Day: 17.12.2015}

@BOOK{BAHaero,
  title = {Aeroelasticity},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1955},
  author = {Raymond L. Bisplinghoff and Holt Ashley and Robert L. Halfman},
  hypernotation = {english},
  language = {polish},
  owner = {Mateusz},
  timestamp = {2015.12.12}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid your question cannot be answered in its current form. For example, if you use Biblatex, it is dead easy. But we have no idea whether you do or no. Please provide a minimal document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, together with a few `.bib` entries such that we can copy-paste-compile the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where might one obtain a copy of the `acm` bibliography style from? It doesn't appear to be included in the TeXLive distribution. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Is using bibtex mandatory? If not, this can easily be achieved using biblatex, In biblatex, the bibliography is printed using the `\printbibliography`command, which can have `key=value` options. The two recant options here are the `type=<entry types to print>` and `nottype=<entry types to not print>` options which controls which entry types are printed in the bibliography. For instance:

```
\printbibliography[nottype=misc]
```

You can then simply issue two `\printbibliography`commands: one for all types except for `@misc`and one for only `@misc` types. I would also define a new heading for the second bibliography using the following:

```
\defbibheading{web}{\section*{Web resources}}
```

The following MWE prints two bibliographies, each with a heading at the `\section*` level.

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
   \bibliography{moje}

\begin{document}

  \cite{BAHaero}
  \cite{matlab1}

  \printbibliography[nottype=misc]

  \defbibheading{web}{\section*{Web resources}}
  \printbibliography[type=misc,heading=web]

\end{document}
```

If you prefer to have the division between the two bibliographies at bit more subtle, use an alternative definition of the “web head”.

```
\defbibheading{web}{\subsubsection*{Web resources}}
```